# Rule in the header

Tags: header-footer, rules

How can I insert a rule in the header of all pages without the `fancyhdr` package?
Is it necessary to use the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem so that the solution can be customized to your situation.  Basically, show us that you have so far.

Comment: "doesn't have the same length of the text": is this the only reason why you don't want to use fancyhdr? I don't see anything wrong with the length of the header rules when I use fancyhdr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, in an attempt to diagnose the problem prematurely (and too long for a comment without visualization), here's a possible scenario causing the difference in length between the header rule and the text block: Choosing the page style *before* modifying the page layout dimensions.

In the minimal example below, the page style is set to `fancy` (from the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)) *before* using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the page layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Setting the page style to `fancy` *after* loading `geometry` yields

[image]

Comment: Great, that is the point! Thank you very much!